# Python "Fast normalized cross correlation"

Tags: python, performance, correlation

I am trying to use the implementation of "Fast Normalized cross correlation" ( http://pastebin.com/x1NJqWWm ) in python to do some template matching. However, even for simple test-images, it produces values out of the [-1:1] range. I can't see what I am doing wrong. Is there a limitation of this algorithm? Help would be much appreciated!

example:

```
# Template creation
t = np.zeros((4,4)) 
t[:,0:3] = 1

# Image creation
image = np.zeros((15,15)) # image

k=1
for i in range(len(image)):
    if k==1:
        image[i,:]=1
        image[:,i]=1
        k=0
    else:
        k=1

# Fast Normalized Cross Correlation
TM = norm_xcorr.TemplateMatch(t, method='both')
result2, ssd = TM(image)
```

This gives values out of the [-1:1] range:

```
>>> np.max(result2)
Out[6]: 8.4913641920299376
>>> np.min(result2)
Out[7]: -3.1869961773458306
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already available in `skimage` [source code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/feature/template.py#L31)

Also see this: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28322/python-normalized-cross-correlation-to-measure-similarites-in-2-images